# Heroku: Build timed out while waiting to start

Tags: heroku

I've been working on a project and have been deploying without issue. However today I made a small update and did git push heroku master as usual, and got the following.

```
Enumerating objects: 883, done.
Counting objects: 100% (883/883), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (881/881), done.
Writing objects: 100% (883/883), 138.47 MiB | 6.48 MiB/s, done.
Total 883 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:  !
remote:  !   Build timed out while waiting to start.
remote:  !
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to xxx.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/xxx.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/xxx.git'
```

I checked https://status.heroku.com/ and it seems to be up. Any ideas?

UPDATE: Heroku status has now updated to reflect the issue.

Comment: hi, it is also happening to me :(

Comment: same on my end atm...I can't push changes to heroku.. can't also open bash. `Service temporarily unavailable. Please try again later.` They posted an issue : `April 26, 00:05 UTC Heroku logging service performance has been degrading for Private Space and Common Runtime apps. Some apps may be missing router logs. We are investing the issues.` Not sure if this is related

Comment: I'm also experiencing the same, now the app is down :( if anyone experiencing the same could you please vote up or leave a comment?

Comment: Happening to me as well for the past couple hours.

Answer (score 1):

[Heroku status has now updated to Fix now](https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2421)